# How to select all input elements with any type (text, radio, checkboxes)?

Tags: jquery, input, selector

I would like to enabled/disabled an input "type=submit" if other inputs are not empty. I found this code and it works fine for input type text, email, pwd... But I would like to add radio and checkboxe inputs to my form.

How can I include them in my selector?

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.field input').on('keyup', function() {
    let empty = false;

    $('.field input').each(function() {
      empty = $(this).val().length == 0;
    });

    if (empty)
      $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
      $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>​
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the `required` attribute? Sometimes, not all form fields are required. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required

Comment: When handling radio or checkboxes you might want to go for their `InputElement.checked` property - which returns a boolean. But don't forget that you can pair radio buttons by name :)